# How do I pass objects between Lists?

Tags: c#, list, xaml, object

I have a list of objects similar to the one below. I need to be able to add these objects to two different lists and then afterwards be able to pass objects between those lists by adding and removing. For context: I am making a card game(Like Top Trumps) So at the start of the game both players are given random cards. During the game, if I win a round, the card I beat should be added to my deck and removed from the opponent's.

```
public void CardComp()
int i;
CardsComp nextCardComp;
var randomEnemyFighter=new Random();
for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    int ranEnemyF = randomEnemyFighter.Next(0, 3);

    switch (ranEnemyF)
    {
        case 1:
            nextCardComp = new CardsComp();
            nextCardComp.cardNameComp = "Tyson";
            nextCardComp.cardPictureComp = "Assets/tyson.png";
            nextCardComp.powerComp = 96;
            tysNum.Text = nextCardComp.powerComp.ToString();
            nextCardComp.speedComp = 83;
            tysSpeed.Text = nextCardComp.speedComp.ToString();
            myListofCardsComp.Add(nextCardComp);
            listOfCardsComp.ItemsSource = myListofCardsComp;
            break;

        case 2:
            nextCardComp = new CardsComp();
            nextCardComp.cardNameComp = "Groves";
            nextCardComp.cardPictureComp = "Assets/groves.png";
            nextCardComp.powerComp = 84;
            tysNum.Text = nextCardComp.powerComp.ToString();
            nextCardComp.speedComp = 88;
            tysSpeed.Text = nextCardComp.speedComp.ToString();
            myListofCardsComp.Add(nextCardComp);
            listOfCardsComp.ItemsSource = myListofCardsComp;
            break;

        default:
            nextCardComp = new CardsComp();
            nextCardComp.cardNameComp = "Ali";
            nextCardComp.cardPictureComp = "Assets/ali.png";
            nextCardComp.powerComp = 86;
            tysNum.Text = nextCardComp.powerComp.ToString();
            nextCardComp.speedComp = 91;
            tysSpeed.Text = nextCardComp.speedComp.ToString();
            myListofCardsComp.Add(nextCardComp);
            listOfCardsComp.ItemsSource = myListofCardsComp;
            break;
    }
}

myListofCardsComp = new List<CardsComp>();
```

Comment: What is your question?  What are you specifically having difficulties with?  List<T> has an Add and a Remove method.

Comment: Using dictionaries which saves index and the key as object can help.

Comment: I would also suggest a Queue data type rather than a List.

Comment: Why is a queue better? Could you provide sample code to pass one of these objects to another list or queue? Sorry, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: If you are using a stack of cards, then a queue better represents the operations you want to do.  You want to add (enqueue) to the end of the pack of cards and remove (dequeue) from the top of the pile of cards.  There are lots of tutorials on how to use Queues.

Comment: the following works:myListofCardsComp.Add(nextCardComp); but if I try to add from a different list like this: myListofCardsComp.Add(nextCard); then I get an error.

Comment: Note that the Queue may or may not be better. It depends on how the collections of cards are actually being used. If cards must be processed first-in, first-out then a Queue is better. But if this is more like a hand of cards, where cards can be selected arbitrarily, then a List or even a HashSet (assuming the CardsComp type overrides Equals/GetHashCode or implements IEquatable) is appropriate.